# recently viewed page "you haven't viewed a page yet"

Tags: php, session

I have some code to show the pages you have recently viewed on my website but if you haven't viewed a page yet i get an error which is

```
Notice: Undefined index: pageurl in C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\recent.php on line 97

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\recent.php on line 97
```

I need it to say you haven't viewed a page yet instead of getting this error
here's the code i have at the moment

```
<?php

foreach( $_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
echo '<a href="'.$value.'">Click here </a>';
echo 'to see last page which is '."'localhost".$value."'".' <br />';
}
?>
```

any ideas?

Comment: this isn't a session_start() issue, he's already done that, its simply missing a for loop as described by one of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add session_start before you check for session

```
if (!isset($_SESSION))
 session_start ();

if (isset($_SESSION['pageurl'])) { 
  foreach( $_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
      echo '<a href="'.$value.'">Click here </a>';
      echo 'to see last page which is '."'localhost".$value."'".' <br />';
  }
} else {
    echo "You haven't viewed a page yet";
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['pageurl']))
  foreach( $_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
  echo '<a href="'.$value.'">Click here </a>';
  echo 'to see last page which is '."'localhost".$value."'".' <br />';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if pageurl is set and is it an array before starting foreach.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['pageurl']) && is_array($_SESSION['pageurl']))
    foreach( $_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
        echo '<a href="'.$value.'">Click here </a>';
        echo 'to see last page which is '."'localhost".$value."'".' <br />';
    }
?>
```